# Removing google translate icon on .chm pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I have a large number of (300+) help pages.  The web version should display the Google Translate dropdown menu, but when these same files are used offline (in Windows help .chm files) the dropdown should be hidden.  Obviously I would not want to maintain two separate help files.

So I have my Google Translate code inside a  called  and created a style sheet that tells the page whether or not to show the translate dropdown (web) or hide it (local file).  This works pretty well, except that I get the Google Translate icon on my local .chm files.

Like I said, the dropdown is not displaying on these local pages, just as expected, but how can I get rid of the icon?  Interesting, too, that this image (untitled.png) shows up with or without the style sheet enabled.

BTW, I am talking about the bigger, blue image, not the Google"G" right in front of the dropdown.
[without dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3dPy.jpg)
[with dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dysf7.jpg)
Thanks for your time!

Comment: I assume you compile the CHM's yourself.  Did you specify the stylesheet *.css directly in the project file?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Like I said, the style sheet is working - it correctly shows or hides the dropdown.  But when I want to hide it, the Google icon shows regardless.  Thank you for your time answering!  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the CSS files are compiled into the help file by adding their names to the [FILES] list in the project (.hhp) file in two ways.

You may add the *.css filename(s) by editing the *.hhp file with a plain text editor or to do this with HH Workshop:

1. Open the .hhp file in HTML Help Workshop.
2. Click the Add/Remove Topic Files button on the Project tab.
3. In the Topic Files dialog box, click Add.
4. In the File Name field at the bottom of the Open dialog box, type *.css (or e.g. *.jpg)
5. Browse to the directory that contains the files (or e.g css), and then select them.
6. Click Open, and then click OK to close the Topic Files dialog box.

Additional information:

The help compiler automatically pulls into the help file all graphics that are referenced in  elements via the "src=" attribute. For graphics that are referenced by other means, such as in a script or style sheet, you must use the above workaround to ensure that they are compiled into the .chm file